# Que pasa al truncar un log Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un archivo de log que pesa 344 Gbs nunca lo han depurado ni truncado lo que pasa es que es la base es de producción, tendría que parar todo?, mi pregunta es que es lo que podría pasar si se trunca en producción?.

ya tengo el respaldo del log, pero en si a ciertas no sabría si tendría algún problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al ser una base de datos en producción tendrás el recovery model a **Full**. El primer cambio que deberías hacer para truncar el log sería cambiarlo a Simple.

- Al hacer este cambio se pierde el punto de recuperación en el tiempo, por lo tanto, se recomienda encarecidamente realizar una copia de seguridad antes de cambiarlo.
- Las copias de seguridad de los registros de transacciones truncarán los registros (si ninguna transacción de larga duración aún lo requiere) y luego podrá reducir el archivo de log. También debes de tener en cuenta que los registros que se encogen también causan problemas de rendimiento pero si lo haces por una sola vez o no muy a menudo, no habría problemas.

¿Puedes hacerlo mientras la base de datos está en uso? Sí, puedes hacerlo pero teniendo estos puntos en mente.

1. Realizar un backup antes de hacer el cambio del recovery model a Simple.
2. Realizar el truncado/shrink (yo lo recomendaria hacer cuando menos actividad tiene la base de datos)
3. Enseguida que termine, volver a cambiar el recovery model a Full.

¿Por qué el archivo de log te creció tanto? 
Supongo que porque no hiciste copias de seguridad del registro de transacciones. Lo ideal sería programar una copia de seguridad adecuada del registro de transacciones para la base de datos.

Comment: Fue un trabajo que nunca se les dio mantenimiento pero nunca me habia tocado que creciera tanto si acaso unos 17 gbs.... es lo mas extraño cuando tuvimos un problema se quiso restaurar y este no nos dejaba porque teniamos insuficiente espacio, gracias por la respuesta  lo hice hoy en la madrugada y ha estado sin problemas

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido y haya ido todo bien :)

Comment: El log de transacciones te permite restaurar la base de datos a cualquier punto en el tiempo. Sin embargo, es inútil si nunca se hacen respaldos. Si no se van a hacer respaldos y se acepta que se puedan perder horas de transacciones, entonces sería bueno cambiar el modelo a simple de forma permanente.